# View environment variable of process on Windows

Tags: windows, process, environment-variables

How do I view the environment variable of a Windows process? Looking for Windows equivalent for something like `environ` file in procfs on Unix.

Comment: [`/proc/<pid>/environ` does **not** give you the current environment of the process](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/70636/44425). It's only the initial environment when spawning the process

Answer (score 32, accepted):

[Process Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) or one of its friends should help.

Comment: should have clarified my question, I was actually looking for 3rd party tool to view env of an arbitrary process

Comment: It does allow you to see it, but it isn't easy to see long values such as PATH or a CLASSPATH. Unfortunately, there seem no copy command available.

Comment: I just found out that to copy the full value of PATH, you can find the visible part using *Cheat Engine* (on the *Process Explorer* process) and then browse the memory region. You can copy the full text from there.

Comment: @Ghost4Man Wow, +1 for a convoluted workaround / hack to solve an annoying UI issue.

Comment: Just found out that "Copy" on the value in Process Explorer *does* now copy the entire value, even if it is truncated in the display. I am using 16.21.

Comment: I found out to copy the environment vars just to double click on the process, and the properties window pops up, then you press Ctrl+A or hold Shift for selecting, and Ctrl+C / V to copy/paste.

Comment: For version 16.30, when clicking on an environment variable, Ctrl+C copies the name and the value of that variable.

Answer (score 2):

Check out **[`GetEnvironmentStrings`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processenv/nf-processenv-getenvironmentstrings)**.

Comment: This is only for the current process. The way I read the question, it's about reading environment variables from a different process.

Answer (score 2):

As ziya suggests, you can use the [SysInternal's Process Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) or, for example, slighly more feature rich [Process Hacker](https://processhacker.sourceforge.io).

Even though it's really trivial, I'll describe how to find the environment variables used by a specific process in any of those two applications:

1. in the list of running processes, select the process you're interested in (in Process Hacker or Process Explorer 16.40 and newer, you can use the search box on the main toolbar)
2. open the process' *Properties* dialog (double-click, press <kbd>Enter</kbd> or click *Properties* in the contect menu)
3. open the *Environment* tab

Process Explorer is displaying all environment variables in a single list, but Process Hacker organizes them into three sections by their scope:

1. **Process**: environment variables specific to the current process (e.g. passed from the command line or defined during the process creation
2. **User**: environment variables defined for the user who owns the process
3. **System**: system-wide environment variables shared by all processes

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [`_environ` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-6.0/aa246807(v=vs.60)).

Answer (score -1):

To get process environment, you must be able to obtain its context. And within the context, use `getenv()` to get specific variable.