# .Net Core - Location of Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

In my Startup file I am using the below code for storing my environment variables as:

```
 Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("use_id", Configuration["Section:UserId"]);
 Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("region", Configuration["Region:Test"]);
```

The code works fine. The only thing being I dont see where these variables are stored. Usually I would see any environment variables to be stored under Advanced System Settings in My Computer properties. But I dont see "user_id" & "region" being there. Is this the correct location where I am looking?

Comment: The variable is stored against the current process: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environmentvariabletarget?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_EnvironmentVariableTarget_Process - your method of checking would only show the value if you'd written it with the `User` target and you were logged in under the same user account as is running your app.

Comment: To view the process: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2255987/361842

Comment: Hmm. When you say "environment variables", are you using these as a "global store" in your application. That's not a normal use for them... they'd normally exist in your environment before the app executes and be used by your app. Things like connection-strings might find their way into your app by this mechanism. IIRC `Configuration` can be configured to read-in environment variables...

Comment: ...so why not just use DI to supply `IConfiguration` and if you depend on it, you can fish your config settings straight from an injected `IConfiguration`? The binding should be automatically set up in most default templates.

Comment: `SetEnvironmentVariable` is essentially the equivalent of using `set` in a console window. It's not persisted past the current console session, much the same as this method only affects the current running process.

Comment: @spender the above was just an example. I am using the above code to setup amazon aws credentials. An using AWS sdk here it cannot read values from appsettings so I have 2 choices either to use credentials file or use environment variables. I decided to use environment variables here. But this is development. Do you see any issues if I use this code in production?

Comment: @ChrisPratt as I have asked in above comment. Do you see any issue if I move this to production ie setting up environment variables like this.

Answer (score 0):

Environment variables can be stored in various places:

- As a system / machine level environment variable: in which case you'd see them under System Values using your current approach.
- As a user level environment variable: in which case you'd see them under the User Values given your current approach if you were logged in under the same user as the account executing the code to set the variables.
- As a process level environment variable; in which case the location you specify does not show this information.

Process is the default / is what's used in your code above.

Documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environmentvariabletarget?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_EnvironmentVariableTarget_Process

For the question of how to see process environment variables, that's been asked & answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2255987/361842